# Neovim color schemes fail on Mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, neovim, color-scheme

Switching from VSCode-Vim to Neovim on my Mac, I'm trying to change some color schemes.

However, when I change with `:colorscheme <color>`, the changes in the window don't reflect what they should.

I originally found this error while trying to load a separate color scheme from github and it didn't work, then tried others and builtin ones and they all are wrong:

Choosing a scheme:
[image: choosing scheme]

After chosen:
[image: after chosen]

It seems all these default schemes are derivative of green highlight on white text on black background.

I figured it probably has something to do with Terminal preferences, but couldn't find any solutions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So you are using the builtin terminal of macOS? If that is the case, probably because the builtin terminal does not support true colors. Get yourself a decent terminal emulator, like, [kitty terminal](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/kitty), [wezterm](https://wezfurlong.org/wezterm/index.html), [iterm2](https://iterm2.com/).

Add the following to your config:

```
set termguicolors
```

Install a color scheme supporting true color, like [gruvbox-material](https://github.com/sainnhe/gruvbox-material).

Switch to it `colorsheme gruvbox-material`. It should work.

Comment: 1 year later, happy to report iterm2 is the best ! Can't confirm for other emulators or `gruvbox`, but I'm glad to know there are other alternatives as well. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the buildin terminal of macOS and Neovim, you can use the color scheme [gruvbox](https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox) with a 256 color palette. This color scheme works for Vim and Neovim in combination with the default terminal of macOS.

To install it, use a plugin manager such as [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) or [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug).
Or you can use [minpac](https://github.com/k-takata/minpac), a minimal package manager for Vim 8 (and Neovim).

Using minpac for example, would look like this in `~/.vimrc` or `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`:

```
packadd minpac
call minpac#init()
call minpac#add('morhetz/gruvbox') 

" set color scheme 
set background=dark    
colorscheme gruvbox
```